# Linking to the NVIDIA OpenGL library

Tags: opengl, cuda, glut, nvidia, glew

I'm trying to properly run an OpenGL program. I'm using a laptop w/ a GT 630M, the OS is Fedora 16 64-bit. It uses bumblebee and I have to use the `optirun` before every executable to get access to the GPU.

Here is the glx info:

```
[sj755@localhost WINDOWS_VERSIONS]$ glxinfo | grep OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string: Tungsten Graphics, Inc
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Sandybridge Mobile 
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 7.11.2
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20
OpenGL extensions:
[sj755@localhost WINDOWS_VERSIONS]$ optirun glxinfo | grep OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: GeForce GT 630M/PCIe/SSE2
OpenGL version string: 4.2.0 NVIDIA 295.49
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.20 NVIDIA via Cg compiler
OpenGL extensions:
```

The program I'm trying to compile is from a book called "Interactive Computer Graphics", and the source code can be downloaded here: http://www.cs.unm.edu/~angel/BOOK/INTERACTIVE_COMPUTER_GRAPHICS/SIXTH_EDITION/

I simply compiled the example programs using the following command:

```
nvcc -o example1 example1.cpp ../../Common/InitShader.cpp -I ../../include/ -I /usr/include/GL/ -L /usr/include/GL/ -lglut -lGL -lGLEW -lGLU -lX11 -lXmu -lXi -lm -lpthread
```

When I run the program like so `optirun ./example1` I get a seg fault. I'm not sure if it's the libraries or maybe the way I compiled it, butin never seems to work.
If I were to try to run the example with `./example1` I get the following error:

```
glXCreateContextAttribsARB not found
```

Any ideas on how to get OpenGL 4.1 working on this laptop?

Note: My CUDA programs do successfully run.

**UPDATE: Output of ldd ./example1**

```
[sj755@localhost WINDOWS_VERSIONS]$ ldd ./example1

    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff31b1c000)
    libglut.so.3 => /usr/lib64/libglut.so.3 (0x00007f4d0b7dc000)
    libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libGL.so.1 (0x0000003990a00000)
    libGLEW.so.1.6 => /usr/lib64/libGLEW.so.1.6 (0x000000389b600000)
    libGLU.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libGLU.so.1 (0x00000038a0000000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libX11.so.6 (0x000000397a800000)
    libXmu.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libXmu.so.6 (0x000000389f800000)
    libXi.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libXi.so.6 (0x000000397c400000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000003976800000)
    libcudart.so.4 => /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart.so.4 (0x00007f4d0b57d000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x0000003983800000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x0000003977400000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x0000003977800000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003976400000)
    libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libXext.so.6 (0x000000397b000000)
    libXxf86vm.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libXxf86vm.so.1 (0x000000398e600000)
    libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libXdamage.so.1 (0x000000397f800000)
    libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib64/libXfixes.so.3 (0x000000397d000000)
    libdrm.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libdrm.so.2 (0x0000003991200000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x0000003976c00000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libxcb.so.1 (0x000000397a000000)
    libXt.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libXt.so.6 (0x0000003996e00000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003976000000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x0000003977000000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libXau.so.6 (0x000000397ac00000)
    libSM.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libSM.so.6 (0x0000003988400000)
    libICE.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libICE.so.6 (0x0000003988800000)
    libuuid.so.1 => /lib64/libuuid.so.1 (0x0000003980800000)
```

Comment: What does the output of `ldd ./example1` show? It is likely that the link loader is finding the mesa OpenGL library and not the NVIDIA one.

Comment: @talonmies Updated question to show the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my programs were linking to NVIDIA's OpenGL library. The problem was with the code itself. This pretty much solved most of my problems: http://openglbook.com/glgenvertexarrays-access-violationsegfault-with-glew/

This explains why I was able to compile and run all the cg examples that used tesselation only found in OpenGL 4.

Comment: Dead link, but found it here: http://web.archive.org/web/20130211010955/http://openglbook.com/glgenvertexarrays-access-violationsegfault-with-glew/

Answer (score 3):

Actually it's a VirtualGL bug.

You can get more info from here: https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/issues/209

The problem can be solved with new (daily) version of virtualgl: http://virtualgl.sourceforge.net/vgl.nightly/ But to get it work you should remove the one, that comes with bumblebee.